# EnableOptimizations = True breaks javascript

Tags: javascript, minify, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS 2015 RC, Mindscape Webtools to minify javascript files and compile LESS files, Typescript to create all my JS files.

When I work in mode "**EnableOptimizations = False**" everything works ok upon debugging.  However when I work with "**EnableOptimizations = True**" I get javascript errors.  Since the JS code is all minified, as I expect to happen when EnableOptimizations = True, I can't do much to figure out why the error occurs in the Javascript debugger.

Not exactly sure how to troubleshoot this.  Any ideas greatly appreciated.  All I can think of is that the minification process is producing faulty results.

Here is my bundle config file:

```
 bundles.Add(
        New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/javascripts").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.anystretch.js",
            "~/Scripts/icheck.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.js",
            "~/Scripts/collections.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.mask.js"
            "~/Scripts/jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.creditCardValidator.js",
            "~/Scripts/Project1/*.js",
            "~/Scripts/MasterJS/*.js"))

**some other bundling of css **

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = True
```

Daniel A. White asks what kind of errors.  They are as follows and are particular to a module I designed in javascript:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'imgCount' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

These errors do not occur when EnableOptimizations is set to "false."

Comment: what kind of errors?

Comment: Two errors related to a module I designed in JS:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'imgCount' of undefined"
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

Comment: So what prevents you from using debugger?

Comment: The Javascript debugger does not allow me to debug when all the JS files are minified, i.e., there is only one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

After a tedious process of elimination I was able to determine that, yes, in fact that problem was do to the process of minification.  When I set EnableOptimizations = True all of the minified javascript files were naturally made into one JS file.  BUT the minified files were not the MOST RECENT minified version of the original JS file.  Hence bogus errors were encountered when EnableOptimizations = True

The problem seems to be, when you work in Typescript, the JS file will automatically be generated but this does not necessarily trigger a re-mininification of the JS file.  This seems to be the fault of Mindscape Webtools - which does not trigger a re-minification when a JS file is changed by Typescript.